# "string is not a type" in namespace

Tags: c++, string, namespaces

I write a program in c++ with two files.

`main.cpp`

```
#include "var.hpp"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
using namespace YU;

int main()
{
    string god = "THL";
    age = 10;
    cout << age << endl;
    cout << god << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

`var.hpp`

```
#ifndef __VAR_H__
#define __VAR_H__

#include <string>

namespace YU
{
    int age;
    string name;
}

#endif
```

When I compilered it, It'get wrong.

the wrong infomation is:

`In file included from main.cpp:1:0:`

`var.hpp:9:5: Error： ‘string’ is not a type name`

I don't know why,I had `include <string>` head file, but it still dosen't work.

I write this code just for practice, not for work.

thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is the namespace of `string` in `var.hpp`. `string` is the `std` namespace, but you are not telling the compiler that. You could fix it by putting `using namespace std;` in `var.hpp`, but the following is a better solution as it doesn't clutter the global namespace with other things from `std`:

```
#ifndef __VAR_H__
#define __VAR_H__

#include <string>

namespace YU
{
    int age;
    std::string name;
}

#endif
```

Answer (score 1):

You have `using namespace std;` in your .cpp file, but it comes after the include of `var.h`. If you're going to write the header like that, you should put `using namespace std;` in the header as well.

Answer (score 1):

Alternativly you could use

```
using std::string;
```

This avoids having to type std::string in front of every string, and you don't grab everything from the global namespace.